# Dynamics 365 Migration from FieldOne Sky to Field Services

Tags: dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Dynamics 365 Migration from FieldOneSky to Field Services

1. Can anyone help on detailed steps.
2. Is there any tools available.

Also tried to delete the FieldOneSky by removing the solution. Still some dependency issues restricting the delete.